# UIView transition animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

`ViewB` and `ViewC` are subviews of `ViewA`.  Say `ViewB` is currently on top of `ViewC`.  I would like to bring `ViewC` on top with flipping animation as shown in the diagram.  I use the `UIView` class method `(void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion`.  However, the `ViewA` gets flipped along with `viewB` which is not the desired behavior.  The desired behavior is only for `ViewB` to flip over and `ViewC` is now on top.  Any idea how to achieve the desired behavior?
[image]

Comment: can you post the actual code, what you have used for from and to view..?

Comment: An easy fix for this (without changing your code) is to group the two views in another 'container' view that have the same size as them before doing `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`. Also if you want to just show/hide the views (instead of add/remove them in the hierarchy) you can just add `UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews` in the options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
 -(void)FilpAnimation
    {
        viewObjB.alpha=1.0;
        viewObjB.hidden=NO;
        [UIView transitionWithView:viewObjB
                          duration:1.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                        animations:^{
                            viewObjB.hidden=YES;
                            viewObjB.alpha=0.0;
                        } completion:nil];

        viewObjC.alpha=0.0;
        viewObjC.hidden=YES;
        [UIView transitionWithView:viewObjC
                          duration:1.5
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                        animations:^{
                            viewObjC.hidden=NO;
                            viewObjC.alpha=1.0;
                        } completion:nil];    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I implemented @Alladinian's recommendation but I think yours will work as well.