# For swift iOS app dev, how do I segue to a view that takes up part of the screen only?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, segue

GroupMe is a good example. I want to implement something similar to this..

[when you press the top left icon it'll bring you to the view on the left hand side, and when you click the right hand side of that view (the chats) it will bring you back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWlLc.png)

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says:

> Use segues to define the flow of your app’s interface. A segue defines
>   a transition between two view controllers in your app’s storyboard
>   file. The starting point of a segue is the button, table row, or
>   gesture recognizer that initiates the segue. The end point of a segue
>   is the view controller you want to display. A segue always presents a
>   new view controller, but you can also use an unwind segue to dismiss a
>   view controller.

As said by Apple© segues are for changing View Controllers only and cannot be used to move single views. I suggest using animations to achieve the effect you are searching, however segues are definitely not what you are looking for. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24320216/uiview-transition-animation) on stackoverflow.com may help you.

And please be sure to check for information by yourself first, I got this information in less than 5 minutes by searching on Google.com.

Regards -Jorge

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know to look for an animation not a segue. Thanks for the link